App Script for filtering the rows in Google Sheets and applying it for multiple sheets
I am currently using the script to filter all the rows in the plan, if there is a checkmark ticked. In addition to that I have a code also showing me all the hidden rows, in case I require to double-check some previous data. For the two filter there is an additional tab created in the google spreadsheet "Custom filter".
The thing is, that the filter only works on a specific sheet, and by simply copying it and creating the same script with different name of the sheet does not provide a desired result. And my lack of knowledge unfortunately leads to nowhere.
Could you please check the code and give me an idea, how can it be adjusted to be able to work for multiple sheets? I would really appreciate your help!
The code which is currently used:
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Custom Filter")
    .addItem("Filter rows", "filterRows")
    .addItem("Show all rows", "showAllRows")
    .addToUi();
}

function filterRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Warehouse_1")
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][10] === true) {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}

function showAllRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Warehouse_1");
  sheet.showRows(1, sheet.getMaxRows());
}


I tried to duplicate the code, create separate script and enter another sheet name "Warehouse_2", but in that case custom filter created is only applied randomly for one of the sheets.

Can you clarify.  Are you trying to apply the filters to multiple named sheets? Or to all sheets (tabs) within this spreadsheet at the same time? Or to just apply to the active sheet?

Hi! I am trying to apply the filter to the active sheet basically.

For active sheet (per comment on original post), try calling just the active sheet as in code below:
    function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Custom Filter")
    .addItem("Filter rows", "filterRows")
    .addItem("Show all rows", "showAllRows")
    .addToUi();
}

function filterRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][10] === true) {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}

function showAllRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.showRows(1, sheet.getMaxRows());
}


Hi Codedabbler!
Thanks for the suggestion.
I tried to do it, but in that case I receive an error stating: "TypeError: sheet.hideRows is not a function". Anything you could suggest to fix that?

I have amended the code, because I copied over my test script.  However, I think in this case, your variables are not declared properly.  sheet in your case is probably still referring to the spreadsheet rather than the sheet itself.  Try copying my entire code and testing that.

Hi Codedabbler! That worked, thanks a lot for your help!

Try this -
Prompt the user to select the sheet they want to filter instead;
function filterRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  // Get the currently selected sheet
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(data[i][10] === true) {
      sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
    }
  }
}

As an added option, you can decide to capture user input with a dialog box using the SpreadsheetApp.getUi() methods.
Loop through sheets, by automatically filtering (conditionally) all sheets with a specific name (e.g., all sheets starting with "Warehouse_"). Might look like this;
function filterAllWarehouses() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    if (sheet.getName().indexOf("Warehouse_") === 0) {
      filterRows(sheet); // Call the filter function with the specific sheet
    }
  }
}

Try implementing this and see if it helps with filtering based on user selection or automatic filtering based on naming conventions.
Remember to update the checkbox column index (currently set to 10) if your checkboxes are in a different column. Also, consider adding error handling (e.g., checking if the sheet exists) for a more robust script.

Hi Emmanuel! Thanks for your reply!
Unfortunately, when I am trying the option to get the currently selected sheet, I receive an error when running the script, stating that "TypeError: sheet.hideRows is not a function".
Is there anything that can be done here?
